# Dynamic initial form data

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to add a button to the customer's page to add a new device but when rendering the form I would like to pass the customer's name as an initial value.

This was my personal Christmas project to make my work projects a bit more centralized in 2021.
Im almost over the finish line but I've hit this bump. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I have two models in separate apps.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    nameF = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    nameL = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    nameN = models.CharField("Nickname", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    address = models.CharField("Address", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    phone = models.CharField("Phone", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=254, blank = True, null = True)
    dateC = models.DateTimeField("Date Created", auto_now_add=True)
    dateU = models.DateTimeField("Last Updated", auto_now=True)
    note = models.TextField("Notes",  blank = True, null = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nameF
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ("cfull", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
```

and

```
class Device(models.Model):

    CONNECTION = (
        ('Local', 'Local'),
        ('IP/DOMAIN', 'IP/DOMAIN'),
        ('P2P', 'P2P')
    )
    TYPE = (
        ('DVR', 'DVR'),
        ('NVR', 'NVR'),
        ('Router', 'Router'),
        ('WLAN Controller', 'WLAN Controller'),
        ('AP', 'AP'),
        ('Doorbell', 'Doorbell'),
        ('Audio Controller', 'Audio Controller'),
        ('Other', 'Other')

    )
    BRAND = (
        ('HikVision', 'HikVision'),
        ('Dahua', 'Dahua'),
        ('Luxul', 'Luxul'),
        ('Trendnet', 'Trendnet'),
        ('Russound', 'Russound'),
        ('Ring', 'Ring'),
        ('Other', 'Other')
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey('customer.Customer', null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    alias = models.CharField("Alias", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    dbrand = models.CharField("Brand", max_length=255, null = True, blank = True, choices=BRAND)
    dtype = models.CharField("Device Type", max_length=255, null = True, blank = True, choices=TYPE)
    connection = models.CharField("Remote Protocol", max_length=255, null = True, blank = True, choices=CONNECTION)
    localaddr = models.CharField("Local IP", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    hostname = models.CharField("Hostname/IP", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    username = models.CharField("Username", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    password = models.CharField("Password", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    model = models.CharField("Model Number", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    serial = models.CharField("Serial Number", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    dateU = models.DateTimeField("Date Uploaded", auto_now_add=True)
    note = models.TextField("Notes",  blank = True, null = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.alias
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ("dfull", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
```

In my project, the individual customer pages are populated with a list of each customer's devices.

```
def CustomerDetailView(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    devices = customer.device_set.all()
    context = {'object':customer, 'devices':devices}
    return render(request, 'customer/cfull.html', context)
```

This is some HTML for the customer's page.

```
   <hr>
<div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="card-title text-center">Customer Options</h2>
</div>
<div class="card card-body">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add Device</a>
    <a href="{% url 'cedit' object.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Edit Customer</a>
    <a href="{% url 'cdelete' object.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Delete Customer</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Which form are you referring to? If that form is to be rendered into the html file above, you have direct access to the customer's name via object.nameF etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add or edit the url that serves the new device form

```
url(r'^device/new/(?P<customer_id>\d+)/$', views.add_device, name='add_device')

path('device/new/<int:customer_id>/', views.add_device, name='add_device'),
```

In the Customers page HTML, include a button that links to the new device form

```
<div class="card card-body">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add Device</a>
    <a href="{% url 'cedit' object.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Edit Customer</a>
    <a href="{% url 'cdelete' object.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Delete Customer</a>
    <a href="{% url 'add_device' object.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Add Device</a>
</div>
```

Update the `add_device` view. in this example, I assume the form name is `DeviceForm`:

```
def add_device(request, customer_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
    else:
        form = DeviceForm(initial={'customer': customer_id})
    return render(request, <insert template path>, {'form': form})
```

Now when you click the add device button on the customers page, the customers name should get selected on the form. You may want to prevent the name from being editable. To do that, disable the customer field in the device form

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer'].disabled = True
    ...
```

Comment: Thank yo so much!! I spent soo much time researching only to find out that my mistake was not setting the dictionary properly in my device form. I feel soo stupid. But thanks again!